# Marking repeating or both in corresponding cell based on the criteria

Tags: vba, excel

i have a sheet in excel which have two columns Col "A" & Col "B"

[image: Image click here]

in col "A" i have values like 1,1,1  - 3 times & 2,2,2,2 - 4 times

and in col "B" i have  yes, yes, yes corresponding to column A value 1,1,1 &

yes, no ,yes no corresponding to column "A" value 2,2,2,2 as shown in the image.

now i want to add some values in col "C" based on codition like

if col "A" 1,1,1 all values are **yes** in col "B" then put SOME TEXT LIKE **"repeating" in Col "C"** in front of  every value of col"A"

and if col "A" 2,2,2,2 all values are different like yes, no, yes , no in col "B" then put SOME TEXT LIKE **"both" in Col "C"** in front of  every value of col"A"

for example see below image.-

[image: image 2 click here]

**-it will check all the similar values in col "A" First suppose it will take "1" first then it will check its corresponding value in col "B" and it will keep on checking all of the values of "1" in col"B" if all values are "yes" then it will simply put "repeating" in col"C" in front of every "1"**

**-but again it will check for all the values of "2" in col"B" if all values are "yes" then it will simply put "repeating" in col"C" in front of every "2" but as you can see all values are not same in front of "2" some are "yes" and some are "no" in col"B" so if all values of "2" are not same in col "B" then it will put "both in col"C" in front of every "2"**

i  want to know is there any formula for doing this or vba code is needed . please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Excel 2016 you can use `COUNTIFS` nested in an `IF` like:

`Countifs` will count the values based on two criteria.

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$7,A1)=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$7,A1,$B$1:$B$7,B1),"Repeating","Both")
```

[image]

You can nest a third condition like this:

```
=IF(B1="may be","Confirm",IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$9,A1)=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$9,A1,$B$1:$B$9,B1),"Repeating","Both"))
```

[image]

**Explanation:**

> The formula consists of two conditional `IF`nested:
>
> The first `IF(B1="may be","Confirm"` evaluates if `B1 = "may be"` when is
>   `true` it returns `"Confirm"`.
>
> when is `false` start the second `IF` to compare one condition:
>
> `COUNTIF($A$1:$A$9,A1)` - `Countsif` function counts values in a range
>   based on one condition. In this case, the criteria are each cell in
>   column `A` and count how many times are this value in the range
>   `$A$1:$A$9`.
>
> `COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$9,A1,$B$1:$B$9,B1)` - `Countifs` function counts
>   values in a range based on multiple conditions. In this case, it is
>   counting based on two criteria for each value in `A` and `B`.

**Evaluating second conditional:**

> **For C1:**
>
> `COUNTIF($A$1:$A$9,A1) = 3` 3 times the value (1) in the range
>   `$A$1:$A$9`.
>
> `COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$9,A1,$B$1:$B$9,B1) = 3` 3 times the values (1) and (yes).
>
> So, if 3 = 3 then "Repeating".
>
> **For C4:**
>
> `COUNTIF($A$1:$A$9,A4) = 4` 4 times the value (2) in the range
>   `$A$1:$A$9`.
>
> `COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$9,A4,$B$1:$B$9,B4) = 2` 2 times the values (2) and (yes).
>
> So, if 4 = 2 is false it returns "Both".

Comment: but what if i have some more values in col "A" like 3,3,3,3 which has values may be, may be, may be , may be in corresponding column col"B" & i want to put "confirm " in col"C " in front of 3 in col" A" along with the other 1, 2 values   @virtualdvid

Comment: You have to nest a third condition in the formula `IF`. How many conditions do you have? Can you update your question to understand better your process?

Comment: only three condition like that i told you just want to know whether it will work for third condition or not. thanks alot for your help @virtualdvid

Comment: I updated my answer. It is an example. Let me know if this is your case. it is not clear to me if the third condition is a mix like you showed in the first case or it is just the word "may be".

Comment: Hi @virtualdvid can you explain your formula because i am trying to implement this in a vba code if you can explain this it will give me some idea to write a vba code for that . thanks much

Comment: I tried, English is not my native language so excuse me if I made a grammar mistake or if it is confusing. It was a good challenge for me :D. Feel free to ask me if you have another question.